# What is the difference between three `echo` commands?

Tags: echo

What are the differences between the three following `echo` commands?

```
var='You'
echo "Hello\nThere\n${var}"
```

Output:

> Hello\nThere\nYou

```
echo 'Hello\nThere\n${var}'
```

Output:

> Hello\nThere\n${var}

```
echo $'Hello\nThere\n${var}'
```

Output:

> Hello
>
> There
>
> ${var}

I understand that single ticks (i.e., `''`) tells echo to interpret all characters within as literals.

But I was expecting the double quotes to print the newlines, but it didn't. And I don't understand why `$''` did print the new lines.

What are the differences between these commands?

Comment: Side note about "I understand that single ticks tells echo …": not echo, they tell *the shell*. Quotes are meaningful to the shell before `echo` even starts. (The fact `echo` is a builtin in many shells does not matter).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski You are correct, it appears that my question is a duplicate. In my searching it did not occur to me that the ticks and quotes are at the shell level.

Comment: `echo $'Hello\nThere\n'$var`